# Deleting edge loops parallel to the z axis of a spehre with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am completely stucked how to delete edge loops which are on a parallel to the planes of a spehre with geometry nodes.
[image: desired result]

Can someone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By comparing the Z position of the 2 end points of all edges you can make a selection to remove all edges whose endpoints have the same z-position.

[image: ![![alt text](image.png)]